# How to save the results of an impala query

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr, impala

I've loaded a large set of data from S3 into hdfs, and then inserted the data to a table in impala.

I then ran a query against this data, and I'm looking to get these results back into S3.

I'm using Amazon EMR, with impala 1.2.4.  If it's not possible to get the results of the query back to S3 directly, are there options to get the data back to hdfs and then some how send it back to S3 from there?

I have messed around with the `impala-shell -o filename` options, but that appears to only work on the local linux file system.

I thought this would have been a common scenario, but having trouble finding any information about saving the results of a query anywhere.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Storing the results in local file system and pushing it to S3 is not a good approach in case of large data. The best approach is to create an external table in S3 and populate the output data into the external table.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the knowledge above I am including the command that writes the query results to a file with a delimeter as we declared using the option **--output_delimeter** and also by using the option 
**--delimeted** which actually switches off the default tab delimeter option.

```
  impala-shell -q "query " --delimited   --output_delimiter='\001'  --print_header -o 'filename'
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do if it's a smallish result set is run the script from the command line then upload to s3 using the AWS command line tool:

```
impala-shell -e "select ble from bla" -o filename
aws s3 cp filename s3://mybucket/filename
```

An alternative is use Hive as the last step in your data pipeline after you've run your query in Impala:

**1. Impala step**:

```
create table processed_data
as
select blah
--do whatever else you need to do in here
from raw_data1
join raw_data2 on a=b
```

**2. Hive step**:

```
create external table export
like processed_data
location 's3://mybucket/export/';

insert into table export
select * from processed_data;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing creating an external table in s3 can't be done with impala?  I originally tried Hive, the only issue I had was a query that took like 10 seconds in impala took about 5 hours in hive...maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: hmm 5 hours sounds a bit excessive, why don't you post your query as a question and see if someone can help you optimise it?

Comment: I think the `impala-shell` command needs a `-q` flag instead of `-e`

Answer (score 0):

If you have aws cli installed you can use standard out of Impala shell , impala shell query | aws cli cp - s3folder/outputfilename 
You can use unix pipe  and stream (-)